# Ms SQL Server. There is no record after insert trigger working

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, triggers

There is trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[dbName_trigger]
    ON [dbo].[dbName] AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @Inserted NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT * FROM INSERTED FOR JSON AUTO)

        IF NOT (@Inserted IS NULL)
            EXECUTE dbo.StoredProcedure 'dbName', @Inserted
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
    END CATCH
END
```

`dbo.StoredProcedure` is .Net stored procedure which is working with RabbitMQ. Stored procedure is got inserted json values and queue it. Queue sends values to the consumers. Consumers is trying to get inserted record from database using Entity Framework.

Sometimes, consumer gets `null` from database. But if repeat query again in second, consumer get record from database. It seems, inserting transaction hasn't been always worked in time. 
Also, I want to clarify consumers try to get record and record is created in different connections.

Can somebody provide any help?

Comment: Something is missing in the code you shared - `@Deleted` is not declared. Please try and create a [mcve].

Comment: @ZoharPeled Sorry, I've changed.

Comment: Did you read the link at all? If I copy this code to a test environment, Do you think it will reproduce the problem?